# image value is NULL Mysql blob

Tags: mysql, blob

I try to insert an image on MySQL database but it gives me NULL

```
insert into productt(nomProduct,price,numCat,image) 
values("Xbox one",4500,2,load_file('E:\2\9.jpg'));
```

I tried with `'E:\2\9.jpg'` and `'E:/2/9.jpg'` both of them give me NULL, what should I do thanks in advance.

Comment: Although it is possible to save images in to the `MySQL` database, I'd highly recommend that you will only save the path of the file in the table.

Comment: @B_CooperA what's the reasoning for this? Could you provide details as to why you do not recommend storing images within the database?